# How can I query a list of strings with Swift using the UISearchBar

Tags: ios, arrays, csv, swift, import

I have a column of 10,000 Strings in a .CSV file.

I prepared the UISearchBar with this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift) which searches through an array.

So my guess would be to somehow import the .CSV or maybe another filetype containing the data and convert it into an array. I did try using [SwiftCSV](https://github.com/naoty/SwiftCSV) to accomplish this but didn't get far (I wish they had more examples).

Does Core Data have the capability to do what I'm asking here?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703372/best-datastore-for-storing-20-000-items-to-be-queried-by-uisearchbar) question is asking something similar but the answers aren't understandable to me.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to read in your CSV file. If it is a really simple file, e.g. one string per line, then simply open it and read it line by line into an array. You can then filter your array for partial search strings by e.g.

```
let searchString = "Foo"
var filtered = strings.filter({ (entry: String) -> Bool in
    return entry.rangeOfString(searchString) != nil
})
```